# Eclipse SVN plugin install fail on mac pro

Tags: macos, svn, eclipse-plugin, subclipse

Yesterday I had install the eclipse and the Android plugin. Everything works perfectly, but I would like to install the SVN plugin too. I had add the suite, and selected the three main components, but when I click on the next it stack in. The eclipse write "Calculateing requriements and dependencies" and than I just waiting.

So I had disabled all another update site and it works, but then I got the following message:
"could not upgrade:missing compnents: svn.rep.grap". It is very good, but I would like to install this component at NOW beside of the another svn tools.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi guys! I`m still works on it, and the install running, but it seems I have to download the Eclipse again, with the Java developers version of it. A lot of package and plugin is in, which were necessary to install the SVN

Comment: solution was: 1.3.5 connector need to select

Answer (score 0):

The Subclipse plugin can be installed from the Eclipse Marketplace Client or by adding the update site URL of http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.8.x

Note that Subclipse requires the JavaHL native library that is part of Subversion.  The easiest way to get this is to install the latest Subversion client distribution provided by CollabNet:

http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/community/

You can also install Subversion via MacPorts.  Both of these include the JavaHL library and properly link it in your System folder so that is visible to the Subclipse plugin running in Eclipse.  I would assume you could also install via Homebrew but I have not tried that option.